# The world of generated NSManagedObjects and a Superclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have several generated NSManagedObject subclasses. Using this [article](http://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/core-data-models-and-model-objects/) I created a parent class (named Qualifier) my NSManagedObject subclasses extend. In this way I can have a class hierarchy without an entity hierarchy.

I have a problem where I won't know until runtime which subclass I need to create. All I have is a string representing the class name. I put a method in the Qualifier class that creates the specific subclass:

```
+ (instancetype) insertNewObjectFor:(NSString *) qualifierName intoContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {

    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectModel];
    Class qualifierClass = NSClassFromString(qualifierName);
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:qualifierName];
    Qualifier *object = [[qualifierClass alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    return(object);

}
```

I'm fairly new at objective c and wanted to ask the more informed stack exchangers if this is an acceptable way to create a specific instance?

Answer (score 0):

That's fine, although it's more steps than necessary. I'd probably simplify it to:

```
Qualifier *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:qualifierName
     inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't know what I was thinking, what you're proposing is far better.